# How to create two layers and switching between them using button

Tags: android, layer

i have to create two layers and switch between them by clicking buttons. for example it should be approximately like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jZQHJw-63s)

can anyone tel me where and how to start. i dont have any idea about this.. i want an idea about this

thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You can create two different layout with different id. Then to select the second layout set first layout visibility gone and to select first layout make second layout gone and first layout visible.

```
youViewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: thanks.. now is it possible to write text dynamically in one layer when it is active? if it is can you give me the idea?